# Any way to open / convert Canvas drawing files on Ubuntu?

Tags: conversion, format-conversion

I have a lot of illustrations from a prior life done in the Windows software [Canvas](https://www.canvasgfx.com/).  The files have `.cvs` extensions. I'd like to convert them to something actually useful in Ubuntu.  Is there any Ubuntu software that can open them?

It's hard to search for this, because I get a zillion `.csv` results!

Comment: Since Linux filenames do not encode the format of the data in the name, except by convention (`*.c`, `*.sh`), . Use the `file` command to see if Linux recognizes the file's format.

Comment: I understand that Canvas can export in a variety of formats. If you can get hold of a Windows machine with Canvas installed, maybe you can export your images to a format Ubuntu can use?

Comment: "filetype .cvs -.csv" reduces the `.csv` hits with Google search or DDG.

Comment: @DKBose I have a windows VM. Maybe I can get a trial version of Canvas. Thanks!

Comment: @DKBose I was able to download a trial version of Canvas, run it in my Windows VM, and recover the files.  Since your comment is what suggested a way to solve my problem, if you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll accept it. In any case, my thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an internet search for *canvas cvs file format -csv* and that led me to https://www.canvasgfx.com/en/support/product-support/supported-file-formats/.

The latter link lists a long variety of image formats that Canvas X 2019 can use as export options. Many of those formats are compatible with software available in Ubuntu.

If possible, you could try to find a Windows machine with Canvas installed and export your images in a format that Ubuntu can use.